# Is Map of lists not possible in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

I have data in this order :-

```
m={ 1:[54,23,98],
    9:[8,4,2]
   }
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this using the following code but it's not working. Where am I going wrong? Is there another way of storing and accessing this type of data in dart if my method is completely wrong?

```
Map<int,List<int>> m;

 m[0]=[];
 m[0].add(5);
```

Comment: What means `the following code but it's not working`? That is, nothing happens at all? Even no explosion in the universe does not occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise it with empty map first

```
  Map<int, List<int>> m={}; //<- initialise it here
  m[0] = [];
  m[0].add(5);
  print(m); // prints {0: [5]}
```